# Best way to store fund on the lightning network

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees, lightning-network, locktime

Suppose that someone want to store 0.1 bitcoin on the lightning network for a period of 1 year to use services such as buying and selling things but doesnt know which one and with who yet.

What would be the best strategy here:

- Open 10 channel for 0.01 BTC today and lock the fund for 1 year with the most used or most connected, funded channel at this day for 1 year, in the hope that they will be connected with the other nodes I want.
- Open 1 channel for 0.1 BTC and lock the fund for 1 year with the single biggest node
- Some custodial services with the impeding loss of control

Comment: Tried to give an answer but i would not be surprised if this is closed as it is kind of opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best strategy really depends on the user. You distinguish tradeoffs in all these solutions:

> - Open a new channel each time

This one does not make sense.

> Open 10 channel for 0.01 BTC

More exposure to DOS (and onchain fees), but less exposure to censorship.
Probably the solution which makes the most of sense (or 5 channels for 2mBTC) since MPP.

> Open 1 channel for 0.1 BTC

Less exposure to DOS (and onchain fees), but more exposure to censorship (you better chose well your single peer!).

> Some custodial services

No exposure to DOS (and any other technical cost), but complete exposure to censorship.